# Using BASH script, how to change lines based upon a pattern?

Tags: sed, design-patterns, lines

I have a file that I need to process

```
##PAT1##
#xxxdx
#ddddvdvc
##PAT2##
#dsfcdsfd
#dsfwf
```

I want to remove leading `#` character, if I pass a pattern pattern. So if I pass `##PAT1##` I want to remove `#` from the next 2 lines (till the next pattern) - always 2 lines after the pattern. I tried with `sed` without success.

Thanks

Comment: please edit your message above to show the output you expect. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

One way using the GNU version of `sed`:

Content of `infile`:

```
"##PAT1##"
"#xxxdx"
"#ddddvdvc"
"##PAT2##"
"#dsfcdsfd"
"#dsfwf"
```

Command:

```
sed '/^"##PAT1##"/,+2 s/^\("\)#\([^#]\)/\1\2/' infile
```

Output:

```
"##PAT1##"
"xxxdx"
"ddddvdvc"
"##PAT2##"
"#dsfcdsfd"
"#dsfwf"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^"##PAT1##/{$!N;$!N;s/#//5g}' file
"##PAT1##"
"xxxdx"
"ddddvdvc"
"##PAT2##"
"#dsfcdsfd"
"#dsfwf
```

Comment: @tuner `$!N` means append a newline and the next line to the pattern space if the current line is not the last line of the file.